# Boolean modifier does not work

Tags: modifiers

Im trying to make an iphone with blender, and for the ports, I was going to use a button to dig in the body. I tried using the bolean modifier but it seems like its not working. The phones body is a plane; could that be the problem? But it's solidified, so as far as I know, it should work.

Plus, even though its solidified, it looks like there are only four vertices for the phone body. Is this normal or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: there are hundreds of question like yours here on stackoverflow, you should search it. If you won't find any, please provide blend file.

Comment: You're not providing enough information to solve the problem. First of all: if you have a plane with a _Solidify_ modifier, yes it's normal the plane still has 4 vertices because the modifier adds "virtual" geometry which only becomes real when you apply it. Next thing is, yes, if the _Boolean_ modifier comes after/below the _Solidify_ it should work. If not there might be plenty of reasons from using the wrong settings to using a "cutter" object with bad geometry to things like you can't see the cut-out because the cutter object blocks the view and you have to make it invisible etc.